# Restore Postgresql data after hdd crash

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, crash, postgresql-8.4

My HDD crashed, so, I can't make a Postgresql backup. It seems that my data tables are OK (I can view the data via pgAdmin). However, when I run pg_dump I get this:

```
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  could not read block 2 of relation 
base/16384/2607: IO error
pg_dump: The command was: SELECT tableoid, oid, conname, connamespace, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = conowner) AS rolname FROM pg_conversion
```

It seems that the system catalog pg_conversion is broken. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't have a corrupt `pg_conversion` table to help perform any verifications. *My answers here must, by necessity, be heavily based on speculation.*

With the limited information we have, I am guessing that you are attempting to do a full database `pg_dump`, along the lines of

```
pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username "postgres" ... "database_name"
```

## Alternative `pg_dump`s?

If your data tables are still OK, you could try to [`pg_dump` the relevant schema(s)...](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

```
pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username "postgres" ... --schema "schema_name" "database_name"
```

or table(s), and use multiple table switches...

```
pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username "postgres" ... --table "table_name" "database_name"
```

With respect to these approaches, I have no idea if this will help, as I've simply never encountered a failing `pg_dump` for any other reason than a syntax error, or something else relatively benign.

## Use `COPY` to make CSVs

As a last ditch effort, if you aren't able to pg_dump your schema or tables, in a compressed `.backup` format, you could always extract the data [using the `COPY` command to make comma-separated variable (CSV) files](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html).

```
COPY table TO '/folder/table_backup.csv' WITH FORMAT CSV;
```

Good luck, and let us know if you have any success.